# Adding leading zeros to the integer part of filenames

Tags: python, string

I have files generated, where the filenames contains within it an integer, but also has a prefix, like so:

`snapshot_data_vss_iter_10000.caffemodel
 snapshot_data_vss_iter_1000.caffemodel
 snapshot_data_vss_iter_500.caffemodel`

How do I pad the integers with leading zeros so I can use `sort()` later?

edit: I am aware of `zfill()`, but that requires me to split the string first to extract the integer part of it, pad it and then replace. I was wondering if there's a more pythonic way to do it

Thank you

Comment: Look into the [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) method: `500.zfill(5)` returns `00500`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using formatting (which is nice with a format string):

```
>>> iters = 500
>>> f'snapshot_data_vss_iter_{iters:05}.caffemodel'
'snapshot_data_vss_iter_00500.caffemodel'
```

The `:05` means to left pad to at least 5 characters using zeros. There are various other things you can do with string formatting, I'd suggest [reading up](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).